# Jensen Inequality - without calculus please

Tags: inequality

Could someone please explain to me what is Jensen Inequality about, without calculus? I know basically what are convex and concave functions - about their positioning in the Cartesian Plane - but I have not found until this day any type of material about Jensen Inequality without the use of calculus.

Comment: The wikipedia page doesn't use any calculus to explain it...

Comment: There is a finite form of Jensen's inequality which doesn't require calculus, and is explained on the Wikipedia page.  The general form is a theorem in calculus, and obviously can't be explained, or even understood, without calculus.  Stick to the finite form, and you should be ok.

Comment: I was reluctant to trust in Wikipedia, since I´ve found some  errors in mathematics articles on Wikipedia to this day. Thank you, though!